# C language : why do i get NULL?

Tags: c, null, runtime-error

about the code:

tp is a pointer to a certain struct which contains a table.

the table is a pointer to a pointer of a differnt struct,used as an array.

size is just the size of the table.

im sending these veriables to a function in order to initialize all the cells in the

array to NULL.

this line:

```
initArr(tp->table,tp->size);
```

sends them to this function:

```
 void initArr(ObjectP* array,int size)
 {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array[i]=NULL;
    }
 }
```

using the eclipse debugger i can see that the objects in the array are infact

being  initialized to NULL, but when the method ends,

tp->table is NULL.

pointers gone wild?

help please.

the structs:

table:

```
  typedef struct Table
    {
        size_t size;
        hashFcn hash;
        printFcn print;
        comparisonFcn comp;
        ObjectP* table;
        int duplicated;
    }Table;
```

object:

```
    typedef struct Object
    {
         void *key;
         ObjectP pointsTo;
    }Object;
```

Comment: Which is this? C or C++? The advice I give you will be *very* different depending on which it is.

Comment: why do you return something in a function returning `void`?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `tp`, it's a bit hard to follow the problem you're describing and the posted code snippet looks OK.

Comment: Post your *actual* code.  The snippet you gave does not compile, since you're trying to return something (`array`) from a function declared `void` that should not return anything.

Comment: Is it just me or there are very many questions with `ObjectP` lately :-/

Comment: What is the value of the pointer of `tp->table` before calling the function ?

Comment: @Cedekasme the value is some location in the memory...

Comment: The value is in some location in the memory but is this location correct ? Have you allocated the memory for the `table` pointer ?

Comment: Are you sure that `tp->size` has the correct value in it ? ie. `tp->size` <= the amount of `ObjectP`'s in the `tp->table` array.

Comment: about the tp->table , yes the memory allocated is OK, and so are the amount of objects in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays and pointers are similar but different.

An array of pointers can be represented as a number of continuous pointers in memory (with an address of where the first pointer in the array resides).

Under such a circumstance tp->table is exactly the same as tp->table[0], but the [0] is assumed (because it has the same address).  In systems that are implemented in this manner, the tp->table specifies an address, and the offset from that address (to get to the element of the array) is represented as a value times the datatype size (or one pointer's size in your case).

```
tp->table (the base address 0x00000100)
tp->table[0] (the address 0x00000100 + 0 * sizeof(... pointer ...) = 0x00000100)
tp->table[1] (the address 0x00000100 + 1 * sizeof(... pointer ...) = 0x00000104 (some systems only))
tp->table[2] (the address 0x00000100 + 2 * sizeof(... pointer ...) = 0x00000108 (some systems only))
```

So your debugger might actually be printing out tp->table which is exactly equivalent to tp->table[0] depending on your compiler's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The code as presented seems wrong (you are returning something from a void function!), but I'm going to take a wild guess and assume that in your actual code, you are trying to set "array" to something (probably via malloc) inside initArr, in which case we have a classic gotcha: You are passing tp->table *by value*, so it does not get changed by initArr: initArr operates on a local copy of tp->table, which is discarded when initArr ends :)

Edit:

Doh - now you've posted the update, it looks like my guess was wrong. :/ Imagine the kudos if I'd got it right! :)